# Flask-Talisman breaks flask-restplus' swagger documentation

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I recently installed [flask-talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman#content-security-policy) and after defining the default Content Security Policy, I realized my Swagger documentation page did not load.

The Swagger documentation page is automatically generated by flask-restplus and it simply stopped loading.

The Content Security Policy (CSP) I defined was like this:

```
csp = {
    'default-src': '\'self\''
}
talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp)
```

Could this be simply solved by adding swagger to the trusted domains in the CSP, like so?

```
csp = {
    'default-src': ["'self'", "*.swagger.com"]
}
talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp)
```

Or do I need to define other parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's because swagger-ui uses [inline scripts](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/master/flask_restplus/templates/swagger-ui.html#L50) and [styles](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/master/flask_restplus/templates/swagger-ui-css.html#L15) -- [here's the open issue tracker for swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3370) and here's the [open issue for flask-restplus](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/504).

flask-talisman allows control on a ['per-view' basis](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman#per-view-options), so you could add the 'unsafe-inline' keyword to your CSP for that endpoint.  If that's not possible with flask-restplus, you could also modify your CSP using before_request for whatever the swagger route prefix is, as outlined [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman/issues/40).

Edit:

A workaround is to use a different CSP for the Swagger view that allows inline scripts and styles:

```py
# Swagger CSP needs to have 'unsafe-inline' in the script-src and style-src fields
SWAGGER_CSP = {
    "script-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
    "style-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"]
}

# update the CSP for the Swagger view function
app.view_functions["swagger_ui.show"].talisman_view_options = {
    "content_security_policy": SWAGGER_CSP
}
```

Comment: Thank you for referring the various issues that exist! Clearly I didn't search well enough.

Comment: does not work for me .. no such method view_functions ...